# Retrieve Storage Variable Name given Storage Location and Contract Source

Tags: solidity, storage, state-variable, get-storage-at, storage-pointer

Is there any easy way to get the storage variable names provided you have the source code and the storage locations of the variables for a contract? For example, for the following [contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7b2a3cf972c3193f26cdec6217d27379b6417bd0#code) I can use

```
solc AToken.sol --storage-layout
```

to obtain the storage layout, which would look something like this:

```
{
  "storage": [
    {
      "astId": 2353,
      "contract": "AToken.sol:AToken",
      "label": "lastInitializedRevision",
      "offset": 0,
      "slot": "0",
      "type": "t_uint256"
    },
    {
      "astId": 2356,
      "contract": "AToken.sol:AToken",
      "label": "initializing",
      "offset": 0,
      "slot": "1",
      "type": "t_bool"
    },
    {
      "astId": 2426,
      "contract": "AToken.sol:AToken",
      "label": "______gap",
      "offset": 0,
      "slot": "2",
      "type": "t_array(t_uint256)50_storage"
    },
    {
      "astId": 1584,
      "contract": "AToken.sol:AToken",
      "label": "_balances",
      "offset": 0,
      "slot": "52",
      "type": "t_mapping(t_address,t_uint256)"
    },
    ...
```

So given a list of storage location hashes e.g. 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000036, etc. I can use

```
web3.utils.getStorageAt('0x7b2a3CF972C3193F26CdeC6217D27379b6417bD0', storage_location_hash)
```

to obtain the value of a given slot for the contract. I can easily discern the variable names of simple variables, like uint256 type - 0x36 is just 54, which tells me the slot number and corresponding variable name. However, storage hashes such as 0xe508bcfa121f037568ba66d134df0df9a711886af8fe244fd9c8cb7cfc1d050c are more complicated to match with their corresponding variables, and I'm unsure how to discern which storage variable these refer to. My guess is they refer to more complicated storage types like mappings().

The only way I can think of to extract the storage variable name for these variables is to attempt to bruteforce different combinations of  inputs to web3.uitls.soliditySha3() based on variables in the state variable layout, e.g. web3.uitls.soliditySha3({type: 'uint', value: 6}) would give me the storage hash of the first element in an int array in storage variable slot 6, but this seems extremely inefficient and a roundabout way of doing things. I would hope that a simpler solution exists that I'm just missing.

***To summarize*: I'm looking for a solution that retrieves the storage variable name provided I have the storage locations and the contract source code**